# Why the part after '\0' of a string can be printed after calling istream::getline

Tags: c++, string, iostream, getline

To consolidate my undstanding to `istream::getline` I tested following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string s("abcdefgh \nijklmnopqrst");        
    string s1;
    stringstream ss(s);
    ss >> s1;
    cout <<"s1:"<< s1 << endl;
    ss.getline(&s1[0], 250, '\n');
    if(s1[0]==' '&&s1[1]=='\0')
      cout << "new s1:"<<s1 << endl;
    getchar();
    return 1;
}
```

To my understanding, `ss.getline` call will extract whitespace and the terminator `'\n'` then assigns whitespace and `'\0'` into `s1[0]` and `s1[1]` separately referring to [cpluscplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/), chars after `s1[1]` keep invariant because extraction stops once terminator reached. But an unexpected point puzzles me is that `s1` can be printed out. The console printed

```
s1:abcdefgh
new s1:  cdefgh
```

Why the part after ‘\0' of a string can be printed in this case?

Comment: Why are you *still using* bad code when everyone in your other question explained why it is wrong? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48413784/puzzling-behavior-of-istreamgetline

Comment: @ZanLynx My compiler will report error when using `ss.getline(s1, 250, '\n')` , and my IDE is visual studio

Comment: @ZanLynx the compiler said no instance of overloaded function found,

Comment: You need to use this one: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ strings and the I/O facilities for working with them don't really care about `NUL` bytes. They know their own length, and if their data is N bytes long, it doesn't matter if some of those bytes are `NUL`, `iostream`s will keep going until they reach the documented length (set when you read with `ss >> s1;`).

You're explicitly misusing your strings here when you do:

```
ss.getline(&s1[0], 250, '\n');
```

because `&s1[0]` is bypassing `std::string`'s safe accessors to get the raw `char*` (worse, you told `getline` it could pull up to 250 characters, when the underlying buffer is likely much smaller), and leaves the length/capacity information untouched (so it still believes it contains however many characters `ss >> s1;` read).

You really wanted [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), which is `std::string` oriented, and would work correctly (including sizing the output for you as needed, adjusting the known string length, ensuring existing data is not left in place):

```
std::getline(ss, s1, '\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` is allowed to contain null characters. Unlike a traditional c-string, the null character is not used to determine its length *(although a null character is stored at the end of it in order to allow it to be used with c-string accepting functions)*. Its length is stored separately, and can be retrieved with either the `size()` or `length()` member function. So when you print it out with `operator<<`, the operator does not stop printing when it finds a null, it stops printing when it has printed `s1.size()` characters.